# Why is sin(pi/4) different from cos(pi/4) in python?

Tags: python-2.7, math, numpy, trigonometry

I wonder why this statement is evaluated false:

```
>>> from numpy import sin,cos,pi
>>> sin(pi/4)==cos(pi/4)
False
```

in fact sine and cosine of pi/4 should be √ 2 / 2. What's happen? And how to avoid this problem?

Comment: Never compare float values on equality. At least use an epsilon. Calculations are never perfectly exact, because you have a limited precision.

Comment: Floating point (Esp. irrational) values can never be accurately expressed.. Print them out individually and check.

Comment: Probably just floating point arithmetics, when I do `numpy.allclose(sin(pi/4), cos(pi/4))` I get `True`.

Comment: @Thrustmaster: floating-point numbers are exactly what floating-point representations CAN represent accurately.  Perhaps you meant to write *real values*. There is a lot of evidence here on SO that people get easily confused and puzzled about floating-point arithmetic and inaccurate statements such as your comment just add to the confusion.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Yup, you are correct. I actually meant "real numbers". :)

Comment: Since "pi/4" can't have an exact floating point representation and cos("pi/4")^2 > 0.5, it only makes sense, that sin("pi/4")^2 < 0.5, since the sum should equal to 1.0 as closely as possible.

Comment: This question is substantially different from the other one.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't say this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken merely cause they both are about the quirkyness of floating point math

Comment: Thanks for your support @SamB it was nine years I was waiting for this moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at what the results actually are:

```
>>> sin(pi/4)
0.70710678118654746
>>> cos(pi/4)
0.70710678118654757
```

You will note that they are very, very close, but not exactly the same. Due to these kinds of floating point representation issues, it is usual to use a threshold to compare values that should be the same:

```
>>> abs(sin(pi/4) - cos(pi/4)) < 1e-9
True
```

Fun fact: using `numpy`'s `sqrt`, too:

```
>>> sqrt(2)/2
0.70710678118654757
>>> sqrt(2)/2 == cos(pi/4)
True
```

Comment: thanks seems sin(pi/4) is not evaluate as sqrt(2)/2...

Comment: @GM - Most likely, cos(pi/4) also isn't. In fact, your pi/4 isn't pi/4, exactly. pi is an irrational number. It cannot be represented exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Because floating point representation isn't always exact and functions like cos and sin are calculated by approximate numerical methods, it is unreasonable to imagine that the results will be bitwise identical. On my machine, I get this when I compare sine and cosine

```
>import numpy
>x=numpy.sin(numpy.pi/4)
>y=numpy.cos(numpy.pi/4)
>print numpy.abs(x-y)/numpy.max(x,y)
1.57009245868e-16
```

ie. the relative error is very close to the IEEE 754 double precision epsilon. If you need to compare two floating point values, compare a delta value to a tolerance, or use `numpy.allclose()`